# elpy-goto-definition doesn't work when jedi:goto-definition does work

Tags: elpy, jedi

After installing a fresh install of emacs on a coworkers machine, I got elpy setup with all the correct packages according to `elpy-config` but `elpy-goto-definition` always returns 'No definition found'. Running `jedi:goto-definition` works as expected, bringing up the expected file and putting the cursor on the definition. I know this is a configuration issue but I cant seem to figure it out despite using my own system as a reference.

```
Elpy Configuration

Emacs.............: 28.0.50
Elpy..............: 1.35.0
Virtualenv........: None
Interactive Python: ipython3 7.17.0 (/usr/bin/ipython3)
RPC virtualenv....: rpc-venv (/home/user/.emacs.d/elpy/rpc-venv)
 Python...........: python3 3.8.6 (/home/user/.emacs.d/elpy/rpc-venv/bin/python3)
 Jedi.............: 0.18.0
 Rope.............: 0.18.0
 Autopep8.........: 1.5.5
 Yapf.............: 0.30.0
 Black............: 20.8b1
Syntax checker....: flake8 (/home/user/.local/bin/flake8)
```

and jedi configs

```
(:emacs-version "28.0.50" :jedi-version "0.3.0")
((:name "sys" :file nil :version "3.8.6 (default, Sep 25 2020, 09:36:53) \n[GCC 10.2.0]")
 (:name "jedi" :file "/home/user/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/jedi/__init__.py" :version "0.18.0")
 (:name "epc" :file "/home/user/.emacs.d/.python-environments/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/epc/__init__.py" :version "0.0.5")
 (:name "sexpdata" :file "/home/user/.emacs.d/.python-environments/default/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sexpdata.py" :version "0.0.3"))
```

I've also tried running in a venv, but to no avail. Is there a specific venv environment that needs to be run?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a work-around? I have the same versions as you quoted. It started failing for me going from Ubuntu to Arch (a distro with newer versions of software)

Comment: Seems to be an issue in elpy: https://github.com/jorgenschaefer/elpy/issues/1795